# Finding a Mobius Transformation using two points

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

In lectures I have seen how to find a Mobius Transformation from 3 points using the ratio of $z_1, z_2, z_3$ and $w_1, w_2, w_3$ but not when only given two. The question word for word is:'Is there exactly one Mobius Transformation, $f$, such that $f(3)=4$ and $f(4)=3$. Justify your answer.'  This is a new topic for me so I know I must be missing something and cant just make $z_3=0$ and $w_3=0$. Thanks

Comment: $\frac{12}z$ is such a transformation. $f(3)=\frac{12}3=4.$ $f(4)=\frac{12}4=3$

Comment: They are looking for "a" transformation, not "the" transformation. You are free to pick a third point yourself and transformed value yourself.

Comment: So sorry I have just realised I copied the question down wrong and said ‘a transformation’ rather than ‘exactly one transformation’. Does this still apply?

Comment: Wait is this more of a yes/no type of question rather than actually mathematically finding something

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not a unique Mobius transformation such that $f(3)=4$ and $f(4)=3$. Take $f(z)=(12/z)$ and $f(z)=(12z/(7z-12))$.